# "Max_bars_back error" but only after several bars

Tags: pine-script-v5

I have coded an indicator that draws market structures as lines on the chart.

It works as it is supposed to for several candles but eventually an error occures: "Pine cannot determinate the referencing length of a series. Try using max_bars_back in the study or strategy function".

I have already tried to use the max_bars_back() in pretty much every single variable  used in the code and even as an argument in the indicator() function but the error is just delayed and eventually it causes the indicator to stop functioning.

Here is the code, fully commented to be more easy to read:

```
//@version=5

//==========DESCRIPTION=============//
//the code creates low and high structures according to this logic:
//At the beginning the high and low structures are just pivots, 
//the structures upadate only when one of them is broken:
//if the low is broken then the new low will be simply another pivot low
//and the new high will be the highest point between the starting point and the break of the low structure.
//if the high is broken then the new high will be another pivot high
//and the new low will be the lowest point between the strating point and the break of the high structure.






indicator('Auto Structures',overlay=true, max_bars_back=500)


//===================================================================================================================================\\
//===================================================================: INPUT :=======================================================\\

//--Pivot{---------------------------------------------------------------------\\
var G_piv     = '|---------------------Pivot----------------------|'
var left      =   input.int    (10, 'left'     , minval=1,  group=G_piv ,    inline='len')  //left and right are the pivots lenghts
var right     =   input.int    (10, 'right'    , minval=1,  group=G_piv ,    inline='len')    
var LTF_colHi =   input.color  (color.blue  , 'LTF'   ,     group=G_piv ,    inline='LTF')  //LTF = Lower Time Frame
var LTF_colLo =   input.color  (color.orange, ''      ,     group=G_piv ,    inline='LTF')
var HTF_colHi =   input.color  (color.green , 'HTF'   ,     group=G_piv ,    inline='HTF')  //HTF = Higher Time Frame
var HTF_colLo =   input.color  (color.red   , ''      ,     group=G_piv ,    inline='HTF')
var bars      =   input.int    (3,'How many candles to confirm a break'  ,  minval=1, maxval=100)
var start     =   input.time   (timestamp('01 Jan 2022 00:00 +0100'), 'Start', group=G_piv, confirm=true) //The code begins reading the structures only after the "start" point
//}


//===================================================================================================================================\\
//=================================================================: VARIABLES :=====================================================\\

var reset=false     // it will be used to restart the Lower Time Frame structures in the "CREATING FIRST STRUCTUES" section

//--Timeframe multiplier variables{-----------------------------------------------------------------\\
var pair = syminfo.tickerid
var bool is_m15 = timeframe.period == '15'
var bool is_H1  = timeframe.period == '60'
var bool is_H4  = timeframe.period == '240'
var bool is_D   = timeframe.period == 'D'

var LTF = is_m15 ? '15' : is_H1 ? '60'  : is_H4 ? '240' : na
var HTF = is_m15 ? '60' : is_H1 ? '240' : is_H4 ? 'D'   : na
//}


//===================================================================================================================================\\
//=================================================================: FUNCTIONS :======================================================\\

//--Timeframe Multiplier{---------------------------------------------------\\
f_mult(_tf) =>
    var int mult = switch
        _tf == 'D'   => is_D   ? 1 : is_H4  ? 6 : is_H1  ? 24 : is_m15 ? 96 : na
        _tf == '240' => is_H4  ? 1 : is_H1  ? 4 : is_m15 ? 16 : na
        _tf == '60'  => is_H1  ? 1 : is_m15 ? 4 : na
        _tf == '15'  => is_m15 ? 1 : na
    mult
//}



//--Pushing pivot values and index into the structures{------------------------------------------------\\
f_array_push(_val_arr, _dex_arr, _val, _dex) =>
    array.push (_val_arr, _val)
    array.push (_dex_arr, _dex)
//}



//--Break Confirmation{-------------------------------------------------------\\
f_break(_num, _valH, _valL) =>
    breakH  = false     //is the high broken?
    breakL  = false     //is the low broken?
    
    bars_up   = 0       //how many bars are above the high
    bars_do   = 0       //how many bars are below the low
    
    for i     = 0 to _num - 1
        if  close[i]  > _valH
            bars_up  += 1
            
        if  close[i]  < _valL
            bars_do  += 1
            
        if  bars_up  >= _num
            breakH   := true
            
        if  bars_do  >= _num
            breakL   := true
            
    [breakH, breakL]
//}



//--Lowest and Highest price reached between a structure generation and its breaking point{----------------------------------------------------\\
f_hi_lo(_arrH, _arrL) =>
    int sizeH = array.size(_arrH)  
    int sizeL = array.size(_arrL)
    
    int lenH  = (sizeH > 0 and time > start) ? (bar_index - array.get(_arrH, sizeH - 1)) : 1    //length of the high structure
    int lenL  = (sizeL > 0 and time > start) ? (bar_index - array.get(_arrL, sizeL - 1)) : 1    //length of the low structure
    
    float lowest    = ta.lowest (lenH)
    float highest   = ta.highest(lenL)
    
    int lowest_dex  = bar_index + ta.lowestbars (lenH)  //index of the lowest price
    int highest_dex = bar_index + ta.highestbars(lenL)  //index of the highest price
    
    [lowest, highest, lowest_dex, highest_dex]
//}



//--Getting the last values and index in the array containing high and low structures{------------------------------------------------------------\\
f_last_val(_val_arrH, _dex_arrH, _val_arrL, _dex_arrL) =>
    var float last_max   = 0.0
    var float last_min   = 0.0
    var int dex_last_max = 0
    var int dex_last_min = 0
    
    if array.size(_val_arrH) > 0 and time > start 
        last_max     := array.get(_val_arrH, array.size(_val_arrH) - 1)
        dex_last_max := array.get(_dex_arrH, array.size(_dex_arrH) - 1)
        
    if array.size(_val_arrL) > 0 and time > start
        last_min     := array.get(_val_arrL, array.size(_val_arrL) - 1)
        dex_last_min := array.get(_dex_arrL, array.size(_dex_arrL) - 1)
        
    [last_max, dex_last_max, last_min, dex_last_min]
//}



//--Logic creating the higher structure{------------------------------------------------------\\

f_structureH(_val_arrH, _val_arrL, _dex_arrH, _dex_arrL, _break, _tf, _lowest, _piv, _indexhi, _indexlo) =>
    var int  break_dex= na
    var bool brokenup = false           //variable used to know if the most recent higher structures has been broken
    var int  c        = 0               //counter used to let the break logic run only once
    
    if array.size(_val_arrH) > 0 and time > start
        if  _break and c == 0 and barstate.isconfirmed   // the _break argument is true only if in the last confirmed bar the break confirmation cryteria is met
            brokenup        := true                      // if the break confirmation cryteria has been met then brokenup will reamin true
            array.push(_val_arrL, _lowest )              // pushing in to the low structure the value and index of [...]
            array.push(_dex_arrL, _indexlo)              // [...] the lowest price reached since the creation of the most recent high structure
            break_dex := bar_index                       // index of the candle that caused the break
            c += 1                                       
            
        if  _indexhi > (break_dex - (bars * f_mult(_tf))) and brokenup == true  //if the most recent high has been broken and a valid pivot is found afterwards [...]
            array.push (_val_arrH, _piv    )                                    //[...] then push a new high pivot in to the high structure to update it
            array.push (_dex_arrH, _indexhi)
            brokenup := false                                                   
            c       := 0                                                        //once the high structure is updated, reset the counter and the breakup values
            
        if  array.size (_val_arrH) > 3                                          //deleting old structures
            array.shift(_val_arrH)
            array.shift(_dex_arrH)
//}



//--Logic creating the lower structure{-------------------------------------------------------\\
f_structureL(_val_arrH, _val_arrL, _dex_arrH, _dex_arrL, _break, _tf, _highest, _piv, _indexhi, _indexlo) =>
    var break_dex       = int(na)
    var bool brokendown = false
    var int  c         = 0                                                      //the low structure works the same as the high one
    
    if array.size(_val_arrL)  > 0 and time > start
        if  _break and c    == 0 and barstate.isconfirmed
            brokendown       := true
            array.push(_val_arrH, _highest)
            array.push(_dex_arrH, _indexhi)
            break_dex := bar_index
            c += 1
            
        if  _indexlo > (break_dex - (bars * f_mult(_tf))) and brokendown == true
            array.push (_val_arrL, _piv    )
            array.push (_dex_arrL, _indexlo)
            brokendown := false
            c         := 0
            
        if  array.size (_val_arrL) > 3
            array.shift(_val_arrL)
            array.shift(_dex_arrL)
//}



//--Drawing Structures as Lines{-----------------------------------------------------\\
f_draw_line(dexH, valH, dexL, valL, _colH, _colL, _wdt) =>
    lineH = line(na)
    lineL = line(na)
    
    if time > start and dexH > 0
        lineH := line.new(dexH, valH, bar_index, valH, color=_colH, width=_wdt)
        
    if time > start and dexL > 0
        lineL := line.new(dexL, valL, bar_index, valL, color=_colL, width=_wdt)
        
    if valH == valH[1]                                  //if the new Line is just the continuation of the old one, then delete the old one[...]
        line.delete(lineH[1])                           //[...]otherwise keep the line saved in memory
        
    if valL == valL[1]
        line.delete(lineL[1])
//}



//===================================================================================================================================\\
//==================================================: DECLARING STRUCTURES' VARIABLES AND ARRAYS :===================================\\


//--Dichiarazione: array e pivot{----------------------------------------------\\
var float[] LTF_highs  = array.new_float(0)  ,  var float[] HTF_highs  = array.new_float(0)
var float[] LTF_lows   = array.new_float(0)  ,  var float[] HTF_lows   = array.new_float(0)
var   int[] LTF_Hindex = array.new_int  (0)  ,  var   int[] HTF_Hindex = array.new_int  (0)                  //Hindex= index of the high structure             
var   int[] LTF_Lindex = array.new_int  (0)  ,  var   int[] HTF_Lindex = array.new_int  (0)                  //Lindex= index of the low structure    

var float   LTF_pivHi       = 0.0            ,  var float   HTF_pivHi       = 0.0                           //pivHi= series containing all the pivot high prices
var float   LTF_pivLo       = 0.0            ,  var float   HTF_pivLo       = 0.0                           //pivLo= series containing all the pivot low prices
var   int   LTF_indexpivLo  = 0              ,  var   int   HTF_indexpivLo  = 0
var   int   LTF_indexpivHi  = 0              ,  var   int   HTF_indexpivHi  = 0

LTF_piv_max   = request.security(pair, LTF, ta.pivothigh(high, left, right))                                
LTF_piv_min   = request.security(pair, LTF, ta.pivotlow (low , left, right))    
HTF_piv_max   = request.security(pair, HTF, ta.pivothigh(high, left, right))
HTF_piv_min   = request.security(pair, HTF, ta.pivotlow (low , left, right))
//}


//===================================================================================================================================\\
//=============================================================: INITIALISING STRUCTURES :=========================================\\

//--Pivot values and index{-------------------------------------------------------------\\

//--Lower Time Frame high structure
if not na(LTF_piv_max)                                                          //if there is a valid high pivot then save its price and index
    LTF_indexpivHi := bar_index[right * f_mult(LTF)]
    LTF_pivHi      := LTF_piv_max
    
    if  (array.size (LTF_highs) == 0 and time > start) or reset                 //if the high structure is empty or reset condition is met[...]
        f_array_push(LTF_highs, LTF_Hindex, LTF_pivHi, LTF_indexpivHi)          //[...], then the first structure is the high pivot itself
        reset:=false

//--Lower Time Frame low structure
if not na(LTF_piv_min)                                                          //the same process is applied on every structure for both Lower and Higher time frames
    LTF_indexpivLo := bar_index[right * f_mult(LTF)]
    LTF_pivLo      := LTF_piv_min  
    
    if  (array.size (LTF_lows) == 0 and time > start) or reset
        f_array_push(LTF_lows, LTF_Lindex, LTF_pivLo, LTF_indexpivLo)
        reset:=false

//--Higher Time Frame high structure
if not na(HTF_piv_max)                                                          //higher time frame's structure does not have a reset condition
    HTF_indexpivHi := bar_index[right * f_mult(HTF)]
    HTF_pivHi      := HTF_piv_max
    
    if  (array.size (HTF_highs) == 0 and time > start)
        f_array_push(HTF_highs, HTF_Hindex, HTF_pivHi, HTF_indexpivHi)


//--Higher Time Frame low structure
if not na(HTF_piv_min)                                
    HTF_indexpivLo := bar_index[right * f_mult(HTF)]
    HTF_pivLo      := HTF_piv_min  
    
    if  (array.size (HTF_lows) == 0 and time > start)
        f_array_push(HTF_lows, HTF_Lindex, HTF_pivLo, HTF_indexpivLo)
//}


//===================================================================================================================================\\
//============================================================: OBTAINING ACTUAL VALUES FROM FUNCTIONS :===================================================\\

//--Lower and Higher Time Frames index and prices of highest and lowest points{----------------------------------------------\\
[LTF_lowest, LTF_highest, LTF_lowestindex, LTF_highestindex] = f_hi_lo(LTF_Hindex, LTF_Lindex)
[HTF_lowest, HTF_highest, HTF_lowestindex, HTF_highestindex] = f_hi_lo(HTF_Hindex, HTF_Lindex)
//}


//--Getting last values and candle index from high and low structure{------------------------------------------------\\
[LTF_last_max, LTF_indexlast_max, LTF_last_min, LTF_indexlast_min] = f_last_val(LTF_highs, LTF_Hindex, LTF_lows, LTF_Lindex)
[HTF_last_max, HTF_indexlast_max, HTF_last_min, HTF_indexlast_min] = f_last_val(HTF_highs, HTF_Hindex, HTF_lows, HTF_Lindex)
//}


//--Reset condition{-----------------------------------------------------------\\
if (HTF_last_max!=HTF_last_max[1]) or (HTF_last_min!=HTF_last_min[1])
    reset:=true                                                       //whenever there is a change in higher time frame structures, them reset the lower time frame ones

    
//}

//===================================================================================================================================\\
//=====================================================: GETTING THE ACTUAL STRUCTURES :=========================================\\

//--Has the most recent structure been broken?{---------------------------------------------------\\
[LTF_breakH, LTF_breakL] = f_break(bars * f_mult(LTF), LTF_last_max, LTF_last_min)
[HTF_breakH, HTF_breakL] = f_break(bars * f_mult(HTF), HTF_last_max, HTF_last_min)
//}

//--Updating structures{---------------------------------------------\\
f_structureH(LTF_highs, LTF_lows, LTF_Hindex, LTF_Lindex, LTF_breakH, LTF, LTF_lowest , LTF_pivHi, LTF_indexpivHi,   LTF_lowestindex)
f_structureH(HTF_highs, HTF_lows, HTF_Hindex, HTF_Lindex, HTF_breakH, HTF, HTF_lowest , HTF_pivHi, HTF_indexpivHi,   HTF_lowestindex)
f_structureL(LTF_highs, LTF_lows, LTF_Hindex, LTF_Lindex, LTF_breakL, LTF, LTF_highest, LTF_pivLo, LTF_highestindex, LTF_indexpivLo )
f_structureL(HTF_highs, HTF_lows, HTF_Hindex, HTF_Lindex, HTF_breakL, HTF, HTF_highest, HTF_pivLo, HTF_highestindex, HTF_indexpivLo )
//}


//===================================================================================================================================\\
//===================================================================: PLOT :========================================================\\



//--Plotting structures{-----------------------------------------------------------------\\
f_draw_line(LTF_indexlast_max, LTF_last_max, LTF_indexlast_min, LTF_last_min, LTF_colHi, LTF_colLo, 1)
f_draw_line(HTF_indexlast_max, HTF_last_max, HTF_indexlast_min, HTF_last_min, HTF_colHi, HTF_colLo, 3)
//}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the function calculatig the highest and lowest.

It is fixable by just adding max_bars_back(time,5000) to that specific part.

basically whenever you need to execute a calculation referencing a certain bar_index, you need to specific the "time" buffer

```
//--Lowest and Highest price reached between a structure generation and its breaking point{----------------------------------------------------\\
f_hi_lo(_arrH, _arrL) =>
    int sizeH = array.size(_arrH)  
    int sizeL = array.size(_arrL)
    
    max_bars_back(time,5000)
    int lenH  = (sizeH > 0 and time > start) ? (bar_index - array.get(_arrH, sizeH - 1)) : 1    //length of the high structure
    int lenL  = (sizeL > 0 and time > start) ? (bar_index - array.get(_arrL, sizeL - 1)) : 1    //length of the low structure
    float lowest    = ta.lowest (lenH)
    float highest   = ta.highest(lenL)
    
    int lowest_dex  = bar_index + ta.lowestbars (lenH)  //index of the lowest price
    int highest_dex = bar_index + ta.highestbars(lenL)  //index of the highest price
    
    [lowest, highest, lowest_dex, highest_dex]
//}
```